# Frontispiece with specific informations

Tags: typography, book-design

i'm really new in latex that I can't do even a single typography task by myself. I'm trying to make a title-page/frontispiece with a specific number and placement of informations, but every time that I pick a close model and try to modify it just don't compile. I want to make something in the format of the image below:

[image: Housman's Lucanus]

The frontispiece needs to contain the Author, Title, Subtitle on the top; a "type of edition" (in this case: EDITORVM IN VSUN EDDIT) and editor on the middle; publisher and date on the bottom.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should take a look at the possibilities of the `titling` package for customisation of the `\maketitle`  command.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably solved this yourself by now. Nevertheless I wanted to provide an easy-to-use answer just in case others are searching for the same thing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
% Some nice font
\usepackage{librebaskerville}
% simplifies letterspacing
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        {\Large \caps{M. ANNAEI LVCANI}} \\[2em]
        {\huge \so{BELLI CIVILIS}}\\[2em]
        {\Large \caps{LIBRI DECEM}}\par\vfill
        {\normalsize \caps{EDITORVM IN VSVM EDIDIT}}\\[1em]
        {\Large \caps{A. E. HOVSMAN}}\par\vfill
        \caps{OXONII}\\[1em]
        \caps{APUD BASILIUM BLACKWELL}\\[1em]
        \caps{MD\textperiodcentered CCCC\textperiodcentered LXX}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

You can customize this to your needs and quite easily so. In order to obtain the look of the document, I've loaded `librebaskerville` and the `soul`-package.

[image: nice titlepage]

Comment: Approved!!! It is similar to the font of the original book :-)